# App rejected of 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, app-store, cllocationmanager

Please guide me with the below mentioned points, as i am not clear about the issue.

> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide 
>       detailed information to the following questions. The more information 
>       you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your review.
>
> 1.) How is background location feature being used while app is running 
>       in the background of iOS device?
>
> 2.) Does the application use geofencing or significant change for 
>       location services?

My app is driver app, location is used to update customer about driver location and find the rides from the customer within an area. Please guide  me for further action,

Update:

Already added this key in plist [image]

Comment: You need provide complete description to user, why you are accessing location.Ex:<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Here you need to provide complete information</string>.

Comment: Include this key also - NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Answer (score 1):

If your app doesn't need to fetch location in background, use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` otherwise use `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Add proper description of why your app asks for users location to `info.plist` for key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

Add the following line in your Info.plist file (right click -> Open as -> Source Code)

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your explanation</string>
```

Refer: [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

---

**EDIT:**

It seems to be no issues. Just answer their questions properly & clearly. And the user should understand why the app needs their location

Comment: my app needs to fetch location in background

Comment: where to use NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, this key doesn't exists in plist

Comment: just add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to plist with proper descrition.

Comment: And what about geofencing? what is that issue